# set imagebutton after listview and before footer tabbar

Tags: android

***Hi,
I want to place two imagebuttons between listview and footer tabbar. If listview contains 10items then the buttons appear at last of the listview after displaying 10items in listview.
Please help.
thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 0):

I think `ListView.addFooterView()` is what you're looking for.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
View view mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_load_more_row, null);

Button footer = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loadMore);

getListView().addFooterView(footer);

setListAdapter(ListViewHelper.getAdapterForContentList(mContent, this));
```

u can add header also in ur listview

Answer (score 0):

Add FooterView in list view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.footer_layout, null);
list.addFooterView(listFooterView);
```

Comment: u most welcome....and also accept right answer so another user get quickly right answer..